# jsonarray adicionando e sobreescrevendo

Tags: java, json

estou criando um jogo e estou na parte de criar monstros e preciso de um arquivo json para guardar os monstros porem quando crio um novo monstros ele escreve em cima do que ja existe como eu arrumo para somente adicionar um novo monstro.

Codigo:

```
import org.json.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Jsonarquivo {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {

File arq = new File("Monstros.Potato");

if(arq.exists() && !arq.isDirectory()){

JSONObject mons_data = new JSONObject();
mons_data.put("Monstro", "Lobo");
mons_data.put("Level", 2);
mons_data.put("HP", 100);

JSONArray mons_array = new JSONArray();
mons_array.put(mons_data);

JSONObject main_data = new JSONObject();
main_data.put("data", mons_array);

FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(arq);
PrintWriter fw_pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

String save = main_data.toString();

fw_pw.println(save);

fw.close();

}
else{

arq.createNewFile();

JSONObject mons_data = new JSONObject();
mons_data.put("Monstro", "Bruxa");
mons_data.put("Level", 1);
mons_data.put("HP", 1);

JSONArray mons_array = new JSONArray();
mons_array.put(mons_data);

JSONObject main_data = new JSONObject();
main_data.put("Data", mons_array);

FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(arq);
PrintWriter fw_pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

String save = main_data.toString();

fw_pw.print(save);

fw.close();

}
}
}
```

Saida:

```
{"data":[{"HP":100,"Monstro":"Lobo","Level":2}]}
```

Como eu preciso que fique:

```
{"data":[{"HP":100,"Monstro":"Lobo","Level":2}{"HP":150,"Monstro":"Bruxa","Level":3}]}
```

OBS: o jogo e infinito o hp e nivel são gerados com base em umas contas, e comforme o jogador adicione mais monstros os dados dele sejam colocados aqui.
ja tentei varias coisas porem nd funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que não estavas a ler o ficheiro e adicionar o novo monstro ao elemento **Data**. Deves alterar o if quando o ficheiro existe para algo do tipo:

```
if(arq.exists() && !arq.isDirectory()){

    String text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("Monstros.Potato")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(text);

    JSONArray mons_array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Data");

    JSONObject mons_data = new JSONObject();
    mons_data.put("Monstro", "Lobo");
    mons_data.put("Level", 2);
    mons_data.put("HP", 100);

    mons_array.put(mons_data);

    jsonObject.put("Data", mons_array);

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(arq);
    PrintWriter fw_pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

    String save = jsonObject.toString();

    fw_pw.println(save);

    fw.close();

} else {
    ...
}
```